# get sub rows from table that include row like rowspan

Tags: java, mysql, spring

In my DB I have two tables:

1. "subjects" table: that include 2 fileds:
   *id, *desctiption,
2. "subSubjects" table that include 4 fileds: 
   *id, *Desctiption, *subject_id, *department_id (primary key of departments    table).
   I need to return list of Subjects that each subject include list of match SubSubjects inside,

The result in view need to be somthings like this:

```
*****************************
subject * sub-subject * dep *
*****************************
sub_1   * sub sub1    * 1   *
        *********************
        * sub sub2    * 2   *
*****************************
sub_2   * sub sub 4   * 1   *
*****************************
sub_3   * sub sub 3   * 1   *
        *********************
        * sub sub 5   * 2   *
        *********************
        * sub sub 6   * 2   *
*****************************
```

I used this query to get from DB table like this table:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN t.id = (SELECT  id -- Sub query
FROM sub_subjects t3

WHERE t3.subject_id = t.subject_id
ORDER BY t3.id
LIMIT  1) THEN q.description
ELSE ''
END AS subjects, t.description AS sub_subjects, t.department_id
FROM sub_subjects t
LEFT JOIN subjects q ON q.id = t.subject_id
ORDER BY t.id
```

How can I pass on this table in java spring? there is a way to get sub rows?

Thank you!

Comment: What you need is to create entities with many-to-many mapping and use hibernate as ORM. Here some stuff https://hellokoding.com/jpa-many-to-many-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this question related to spring.
In order to get table entities you should use jdbc or orm e.g. hibernate with manytomany relation